# Most run time efficient way to compare two very large numbers (bigger than long)

Tags: java, numbers, compare, biginteger

I want to compare two very large numbers.

My current method works, but it takes longer than 2000 ms on some inputs.

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;

public class comparelarge {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        String first = bf.readLine();
        String second = bf.readLine();
        BigInteger big1 = new BigInteger(first);
        BigInteger big2 = new BigInteger(second);

        if(big1.compareTo(big2) == 1){
            out.println('>');
            out.flush();
        }
        else if(big1.compareTo(big2) == -1){
            out.println('<');
            out.flush();
        }
        else{
            out.println('=');
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise on how I can accurately compare large numbers without excessive run time.

Answer (score 3):

1.) You are doing the `compareTo` twice; store the result in a variable and reuse it. (Dont compare to `1/-1` compare to `>0` and `<0`

There are some things/optimization directly on the Strings, but you need to be careful as these can lead to wrong answers with some Number formats. In my opinion it is best to be safe and stick to `BigInteger`.

2.) if you have only positive numbers and not ones that have `0` prefixes; you can do a check on the `String.length` the longer string contains the bigger number.

3.) On same length Strings you can do a String.compareTo() bypassing `BigInteger` altogether.

Comment: i edited the code and used compareto 1 time as you mentioned in point 1
and the input can contain 0 prefixes so string.length not helpful at that moment ,
still i am getting time limit exceeded :( 
any more help would be appreciated 
thanks.

Comment: How "large" are these numbers exactly? If you have two strings, you can eliminate the leading zeroes and then simply compare the lengths, or if they are the same, the digits, beginning from the "top". As long as the digits are the same, go to the next pair until one is higher. That could be faster than converting to BigInteger.

Comment: time limit exceeded on a test when the input was over 50 digit number ,(no leading zeros)

Comment: @Omar: It shouldn't take longer than 2000ms to compare two 50 or even 100 digit strings. And If the string lengths are different, the longest one is the greater number (assuming positive values).